# Iron:Router Error Couldn't find a template

Tags: meteor, iron-router, angular-meteor

I have a project implemented in MeteorJS.
To do the routing, I installed Iron:Router

```
meteor add iron:router@1.0.0-pre4
```

I have a "lib" folder containing a router.js:

```
Router.configure ({
  layoutTemplate: 'baseLayout'
});
```

I have a "client" folder that contains a "baseLayout" folder with baseLayout.html:

```
<template name = 'baseLayout'>
UPF App Test
     <a href="{{pathFor'home'}}"> Home </a>
     {{> yield}}
</template>
```

When starting with meteor it shows me the following error:

**Could not find a template named "baseLayout" or "baseLayout". Are you sure you defined it?**

I searched everywhere, tried changing the version of iron: router, using {{> spinner}} instead of {{> yield}} and it does not work at all :(

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
# Check this file (and the other files in this directory) into your repository.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

meteor-base@1.1.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.5       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.2.2                   # The database Meteor supports right now
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
tracker@1.1.3                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.3.5   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@2.1.2    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.6.15                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers
ecmascript@0.8.3              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
shell-server@0.2.4            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command

autopublish@1.0.7             # Publish all data to the clients (for prototyping)
insecure@1.0.7                # Allow all DB writes from clients (for prototyping)
angular-templates
simple:json-routes
iron:router@1.0.0-pre4
```

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried this, but I've occasionally run into package and routing issues while using WebStorm's built-in run/debug tools. In these cases I've found that restarting the meteor server is a good troubleshooting step.

Comment: Which other iron:router versions did you try?

Comment: @Dom I tried with most of the versions that I found on the internet: / and yes, I already tried restarting the meteor server

Comment: Could you please share baseLayout.html

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure what this could be, then. It sounds like you've already investigated this part, but maybe you could share your directory structure? 

Is that error ("Could not find a template...") in your server-side or your client-side console? I'm assuming client, but at this point one can't be too specific. 

I assume the same error happens if you render the layout using `this.layout(...)` inside of the route instead of `Router.configure(...)`?

Comment: @PankajJatav The baseLayout.html is written (it's basic, it only contains the settings).

Comment: @Dom The organization is simple:
client/baseLayout/baseLayout.html --- lib/router.js.
this.layout is it possible to use it in the "layoutTemplate"?

Comment: Is that space in `</ template>` on purpose?

Comment: @MichelFloyd no, I was wrong to write the code here :/ I'm sorry, edit

Comment: @JoséAntonioCamusGodoy, this.layout would be used inside of your route rules (in lib/router.js). Such is the first example here: http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#layouts . I'm not certain that this would help, but it would say something if it worked one way and not the other.